# How to install firefox Vimium-FF addon using bash?

Tags: bash, firefox

I can install [Vimium-FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimium-ff/) from their website.

After installing a new OS to my pc, I have to install and configure many things. So, I want to make a script that do this job. But, I can't find any command that can install Vimium-FF in firefox browser.
Is it possible to install this using bash?
If it is possible then how?

Comment: Related https://askubuntu.com/questions/73474/how-to-install-firefox-addon-from-command-line-in-scripts#73480

Comment: @GillesQuenot But What can I put instead of `addon-1865-latest.xpi`?